# How: Add text in back-to-top button

Tags: javascript, css, html

thanks for visiting.
I need to know how can I add in my back-to-top button a "text" saying:
"Back to top" or similar.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 // browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
 var offset = 300,
  //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
  offset_opacity = 1200,
  //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
  scroll_top_duration = 700,
  //grab the "back to top" link
  $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');

 //hide or show the "back to top" link
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
   $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
  }
 });

 //smooth scroll to top
 $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('body,html').animate({
   scrollTop: 0 ,
    }, scroll_top_duration
  );
 });

});
```

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  height:1200px;
  background-color:#242424;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
body > div {
  width:100%;
  height:75px;
  background-color:#393939;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  }
.text {
  font-size:40px;
  color:white;
  line-height:75px;
  }
.cd-container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
.cd-container::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-top {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(231, 142, 46, 0.8) url(https://codyhouse.co/demo/back-to-top/img/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible, .cd-top.cd-fade-out, .no-touch .cd-top:hover {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.cd-top.cd-fade-out {
  opacity: .5;
}
.no-touch .cd-top:hover {
    color:#1769ff;
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-top {
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-top {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
   <div>
  <span class="text"> Scrolldown.</span>
     </div>
<a href="#0" class="cd-top">BackToToP</a>
  <!-- Im using Back to Top from here:
https://codyhouse.co/demo/back-to-top/index.html
-->
  </body>
  
 </html>
```

If you see, I add "BackToTop" text but nothing happend.

I tried using different ways but I dont know how.
Thanks.

Comment: Im not asking you guys do all the work. I just need a guide or  litle crumb to continue working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove `text-indent: 100%`.
That will push the text back to it's original position.

---

**EDIT:**

If you then want the text to be next to the arrow you can do something like this:

```
.cd-top {
   text-indent: 0;
   width: auto;
   line-height: 40px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
   background-position: right 20px center;
}
```

Combined with your code:

```
.cd-top {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   width: auto;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 40px;
   right: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: Arial;
   text-indent: 0;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #FFF;
   white-space: nowrap;
   background: rgba(231, 142, 46, 0.8) url(https://codyhouse.co/demo/back-to-top/img/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat right 20px center;
   padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
   -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
   transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
```

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't saw it. Thanks you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Check my updated answer where I have placed the text in the same line as the arrow.

Comment: Thanks you, works 100% fine and I working on it changing style etc.

Answer (score 0):

The css property 'text-indent' is the one giving you the issue. Remove it and you will see the text. A good way to debug this kind of stuff is using developer tools and then inspecting the element.

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to work in the text, to show it under or in the same line.